# Python issues, mechanize bots

Tags: python, request, bots, mechanize

I'm trying to make a bot in order to reset my router easily, so I'm using mechanize for this task.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open("http://192.168.0.1/")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['loginUsername']='support'
br.form['loginPassword']='71689637'
response=br.submit()

if(response.read().find("wifi")) != -1:
    # ?????
```

If it finds the string 'wifi', it means the bot has logged in, but here's where I get stuck, because the restart button is in another tab (Another page, I guess that from the same object indicating the new URL it should be able to follow the redirection URL without logging off). However, the button from that tab is, well, a button but not a form.

*Picture 1:*

[image: pic 1]

*Picture 2:*

[image: pic 2]

And here's the source:

https://github.com/SharkiPy/Code-stackoverflow/blob/master/Source

Comment: I think you can post links to images without any minimum reputation. You just need some minimum rep to inline them. If you provide links to helpful images, someone with sufficient privileges can inline them for you.

Comment: Maybe you should use a browser-automation system, like Selenium. It makes it really easy to navigate a website, and being slow is not an issue in your case

Comment: @anothernode I got it, there you guys can see the links

Comment: It would probably be much easier to automate logging in via ssh and changing the same setting with one or two commands. It would depend on your router I suppose, but if I were a betting man...

Comment: @Evan could you give me some examples about it? I mean, the main reason why I'm doing this is because I'd like to change my IP trought restarting my router, but in a easy way, I know there are some programs to do this, but I need to make my own script. So, I thought this one could be the right one, or atleast the easier

Comment: @alexboal What is the make and model of your router?

Comment: @Evan router vodafone model tc7230.o I'm from spain though

Comment: @alexboal I did some searching around, (https://foro.vodafone.es/t5/Vodafone-Fibra/Configuracion-y-manual-Router-TC7230/td-p/682442/page/2) and it does not seem as though there is a manual for this router. If you find a way to set up ssh (secure shell) on that router, there are various solutions depending on your operating system. If you are on Windows, I would try using Paramiko. If you are on Linux, I would recommend pexpect. There is usually documentation for routers when it comes to what commands you can use, so I would not have high hopes in this case. Very odd...

Comment: @Evan I see, it's such a pity, if only I could press that button with Python, it'd be easier. Anyway, thank you a lot for your time!

Comment: @alexboal If you don't mind seeing the browser actually open, you should use Selenium as was suggested by CoMartel.

Comment: @Evan Okay, I was testing and that's insane, even it's faster than I had hoped, it works perfectly and being honest is kind of easy to use. Thanks both! I was wondering if there's a way to hide that browser because it's a little annnoying, but if there ins't a way to hide it, it doesn't matter at all. However, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @anothernode Thanks a lot! is there someway to hide that browser?

Comment: I have zero experience with Selenium so I have no idea. If you can't find an answer by searching SO and Google, just create another question :)

Comment: Sorry I meant @CoMartel haha

Comment: Yes you can hide the browser by using selenium + PhantomJS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start of code using Selenium, with hidden browser. You just have to add the actions you take when browsing through your router. I hope it can get you started!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException,InvalidElementStateException,ElementNotInteractableException, StaleElementReferenceException, ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# There may be some unnecessary import above

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options_chrome = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options_chrome.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' # PATH to your chrome driver (you can also use firefox or any other browser, but options below will not be exactly the same
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2} # disable notification by default
options_chrome.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

#### below are options for headless chrome
#options_chrome.add_argument('headless')
#options_chrome.add_argument("disable-gpu")
#options_chrome.add_argument("--start-maximized")
#options_chrome.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
#options_chrome.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
#### You should uncomment these lines when your code will be working

# starting browser : 
browser = webdriver.Chrome( options=options_chrome)

# go to the router page :
browser.get("http://192.168.0.1/")

# connect 
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("loginUsername")
elem.send_keys('support')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("loginPassword")
elem.send_keys('71689637')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# here you need to find your button and click it
button = browser.find_element_by_[Whatever works for you]
button.click()
```